# What are the accumulated major injuries/wounds James Bond has received in the film franchise?

Tags: character, james-bond

We just watched a documentary on the various actors that played James Bond. The spy has taken his lumps over the years, but the show didn't explore that aspect of the character.  What are the accumulated major injuries/wounds James Bond has received from 1962's *Dr. No* through to 2012's *Skyfall?*

Comment: I recall seeing reference to a satirical article that posited that James Bond would be dead a dozen times over from the injuries he had received in the course of the movies..

Comment: Yes. It's a suspension of disbelief to think he'd be able to  perform more than one or two missions before he was physically broken.

Comment: The worst is the broken heart.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Totally agree. OHMSS - the final scene is heartbreaking and without doubt the worst thing that ever happened to Bond IMHO.

Comment: @Coomie *The worst is the broken heart*?? Am I the only one who saw the [torture scene in Casino Royale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_y7YEIphts)?? I don't think we'll be seeing any Bond juniors any time soon...

Comment: @Daft - have you seen OHMSS? If not, it's definitely worth a watch, as one of the most under-rated, and definitely most poignant, Bond film.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod you're talking about his wife being murdered at the very end right? After their wedding? I don't think the OP is referring to emotional pain.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod *The spy has taken his lumps over the years*... makes me think of physical injuries. Maybe I'm mistaken though.

Comment: I agree with you, of course, which is why I put that as a comment rather than as an answer.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod ah, sorry. Didn't mean to imply you didn't understand the question.

Comment: I didn't take your comments as suggesting I was being Daft.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod OHMSS is my favourite of all the Bond films - It was a big (yet temporary) change for the franchise that showed Bond as more human and less superhero. Lazenby is my favourite Bond by far the best actor and Aussie.

Comment: In the books he would more likely have died from the massive amount of alcohol and cigars he consumed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[007 By the Numbers: Every James Bond Statistic You Never Knew You Needed to Know](http://www.movies.com/movie-news/james-bond-statistics/10208) has some info (their title is clearly not truly accurate as they are missing this statistic in full):

> Number of times Bond is knocked unconscious by a blow to the head: 11
>
> By a drug (hidden in his drink, airborne powder or gas, blowdart, etc): 6

EDIT: Turns out [he's been shot at 4662 times](http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21428633.600-die-another-day.html#.VPCBRvmsUgI) and 130 attempts made on his life